# Powershell Output as an Array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, powershell, subprocess

Im trying to put the Porwershell Output from `Get-Printer | select Name` into an Option Menu. How do i put the Output into an Array for example? Currently the Output is only in One Line. Each Printer is suppost to be one Option.

Im using tkinter.
Here is my OptionMenu

```
variable = StringVar(tkWindow)
variable.set(OptionList[0])
optionPrinter = OptionMenu(framePrinter, variable, *OptionList)
optionPrinter.place(x=5, y=35, width=270, height=25)
```

My Powershell Process look like this:

```
process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","Get-Printer | select Name"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
result=process.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Use `... |Select -Expand Name`, and each line of output will be an array item

Comment: Unfortunately the Output is still a String. All the Printer are in one Option. But now they are in a second Option instead of the first. The first is now empty.

Comment: I said _per line_ :) `result.splitlines()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select -Expand Name` seems to be working fine but as you are taking entire output of process into python variable it is treating it as a single line.

You need to split the result into an array like `result=process.communicate()[0].splitlines()`.

sample code looks like this

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","Get-Printer | select -Expand Name"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
result=process.communicate()[0].splitlines()
print(result[0])
print(result[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is any specific reason why you are using PowerShell to search for printers. you can easily do with [pypiwin32](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/) module.

After installing this module you can use inline python code to get list of printers with just one line `win32print.EnumPrinters(5)`.

```
import win32print

printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(5)
print(printers)
```

Comment: You are right that's much easier. But how do i only get the Printer Name (i tried GetPrinter so far). And also how do i set One Name for each Option? Does `splitlines()` work too?

Comment: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32print.html